# MVC 5 - Adding Users To A Role Validation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am experiencing problems with adding users to roles within MVC 5.
When I run the code block I get "**Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.**"

Then when I check the entity validation errors they aren't very helpful.

{System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult} is what I get.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {

            //Gets the user details
            ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            //Add the user to a role, using id ...
            this.UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, RoleName);

            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";

            // prepopulate roles for the view dropdown
            var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = list;

            return View("ManageUserRoles");
        }      
    }
```

And this is the UserManager:

```
        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

I am really frustrated at this point as this is the first time I am working with roles in MVC, and so far it has not been a good experience.

I hope someone here can help me find a solution to my problem.

P.S. The code Im using is based off this tutorial: [Working with Roles in ASP.NET Identity for MVC](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc)

This is the view:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<p>
    Username : @Html.TextBox("UserName")
    Role Name: @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, "Select ...")

</p>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

This is the Default user class, with an added property:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(13)]
    [MinLength(13)]
    [Key]
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:I Found the problem... Because EF uses names followed by ID as a default key, my Application kept confusing the UserID (which was a id number) with the Id field.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Ill edit and add now...

Comment: Where is the exception getting thrown? I used the same tutorial and code in one of my applications and it's working fine. Is the Identity tables present in the DB?

Comment: On "AddToRole" I have a suspicion it might be the user,Id... The guid value might be causing a problem?

Comment: The `GUID` for the user is it's primary identifier. That will not cause any problems.

Comment: Property: UserId Error: The field UserId must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '13'.

Comment: It seems that I dug my own grave by adding a field to the constructor with ID in it, somehow this confused my underlying context.  I figured it out in the end.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you catch the exception `DbEntityValidationResult` and check the validation errors?

There you can check which property is wrong and why. You can get this error if any of the data is not satisfying model attributes rules (for example the required constraint).

Try adding the following statement...

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var errors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var error in errors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Property: UserId Error: The field UserId must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '13'.

I think I might know whats happening...  I added a value to the User model which is an ID number

Comment: Great! post the user model in your question

Comment: I added it at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks so much, this solution led me to find the answer I needed.  I found it very interesting.  Turns out that IDNumber field confused my application... Instead of trying to insert the value into Id.. it tried to insert into the IDNumber field.  Wish I could upvote.  Thanks for some guidance!